Calculating the Length of the Front of a House in QGIS
I would like to calculate the length of the front of a house (a layer of houses) in QGIS. I know how to manually measure each house but i am looking for a way to measure it for all houses in the layer.
i tried using AI to help me but it doenst work for me:
To calculate the length of the front facade (street side) of a building in QGIS, follow these steps:
Make sure you have a polygon layer with the buildings.
Open the attribute table of the building layer and enable editing mode.
Open the Field Calculator and create a new field for the facade length, e.g. "facade_length". Select the field type as Decimal number (real).
In the expression box:
Click on the $length function
Click the space and type "boundary("
Double-click on the geometry field of the building layer, e.g. "geometry"
Type ")"
**The full expression will look something like: $length(boundary("geometry"))
**  <--- did part didnt work for me
Click OK to calculate the length of the boundary (perimeter) of each building in the new "facade_length" field.
Open the Field Calculator again for the same "facade_length" field.
In the expression box:
Click on the minimize function
Click the space and type "array_foreach("
Click on the $length function
Click the space and type "boundary(simplify("
Double-click on the geometry field, e.g. "geometry"
Type ", 10))"
Type ", @element)"
The full expression will look something like: minimize(array_foreach($length(boundary(simplify("geometry", 10))), @element))
Click OK to calculate the minimum length of the simplified boundary, which will approximate the street-facing facade length.
Following these steps, you will get an estimate of the street-facing facade length for each building in the "facade_length" field. The simplification of 10 meters filters out small protrusions.
Some notes:
Make sure the buildings are polygons and not lines or points.
Adjust the simplification value of 10 if needed for accuracy.
You can style the building layer to visualize the facade length based on the new "facade_length" field.
